# 2 UAN Numbers allotted to my PAN Number

Tags: india, provident-fund

2 UAN Numbers allotted to my PAN Number (**AXXXXXXXXX**) as part of my job change.

I was allotted a UAN number (**UAN1**) during my tenure with **Company1** in Bangalore, after which I switched over to **Company2** in Bangalore itself where I worked for about 3 months.

When I joined **Company2** in Bangalore, I provided my previous UAN reference (**UAN1**) but I'm not sure why it didn't reflect in their records.

I then joined **Company3** in Hyderabad, where I am allotted a new UAN (**UAN2**) as the previous UAN that I had acquired from **Company1** wasn't reflecting on my **Company2**'s records when checked by **Company3** Finance team.

How do I get the PF accounts from all the three companies be pointed to the latest UAN so that there are no issues while withdrawing the same?

Answer (score 1):

<s>Option 1: You can write to  uanepf@epfindia.gov.in giving the details of both the UAN's.

This will be able to merge both these under the current EPF.</s>

Option 2: You can request a transfer of EPF from old EPF [under different UAN] to the current EPF. This can be done by submitting the required form. Your company should be able to assist you with the paperwork. Alternatively if you are registered online with [EPFO India](http://epfindia.gov.in/site_en/For_Employees.php?id=sm2_index), you can submit the request online. Once submitted, the system will identify that a duplicate UAN has been issued and automatically merge the accounts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but for the benefit of the others I would want to correct you that Option-1 is no longer working. A mail sent to this email id gives you an automatic response to redirect to this site **www.epfindia.gov.in  >> OUR Services >> For EMPLOYEES >> UAN Helpdesk**, the link to which is broken!

Comment: @Dheer I am able to login on this portal https://unifiedportal-mem.epfindia.gov.in/memberinterface/ but I couldn't find to raise a request online to transfer funds from old UAN to new UAN and merge into a single UAN can you please suggest

Comment: @TGMCians For some months I am not able to login to the portal. So can't help much.

Comment: @Dheer you mean this transfer request http://imgur.com/a/oZVRv ?

Comment: @AjayS, you're right!